# Prevent Gitbook from converting relative links

Tags: gitbook

Our gitbook documentation must have crosslinks to other documentation hosted on the same server at different location.

We have these links:

```
<a href="/stuff/documentation/api-reference.html">API Reference</a>
[API Reference](/stuff/documentation/api-reference.html)
```

Both of these links are converted by Gitbook to links relative to current page (this is for a page nested 1 level deeper than index page):

```
<a href="../stuff/documentation/api-reference.html">API Reference</a>
```

And If page with link is nested deeper:

```
<a href="../../../stuff/documentation/api-reference.html">API Reference</a>
```

What we need is Gitbook to keep relative URLs in links exactly "as is", so they will lead to correct path on final docs server:

```
<a href="/stuff/documentation/api-reference.html">API Reference</a>
```

So far the only solution which works is to put JS code to navigate to desired relative path in HTML `<a>` tag inside markdown but this is a really ugly workaround.